# Executing Oracle command through C# - Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle12c

I am using Oracle 12c as a database, C# Web Application. I am trying to execute an Oracle query from C# and load the data to the data table. I am getting an error like ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended. I ran the same query in Toad and was getting the same error first time, but if I ran the same query again in the toad, the data is returning results. I am not sure, what is the syntax issue.

I have tried the below code:

```
  using (var cmd = new OracleCommand {Connection = cn}) 
            {
                var selectStatement =  "select * from tablename OFFSET @Offset ROWS FETCH NEXT 10000 ROWS ONLY;";

                 cn.Open(); 
                 cmd.CommandText = selectStatement;

                 cmd.Parameters.Add("@Offset", OracleDbType.Int64); 
                 for (var index = 0; index < totalRecords; index++) 
                 { 
                     if (index % 10000 == 0) 
                     {
                         cmd.Parameters["@Offset"].Value = index; 
                         var dt = new DataTable()
                         {
                               TableName = tblName+"_"+index};
                               dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                               dataTables.Add(dt);
                               tableIndex += 1;
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }
```

I am trying to fetch the results in a paged manner. The error is shown in line cmd.ExecuteReader. How to fix this?

Update 1: Two solution which worked for this issue.

```
 var selectStatement = "Select * from tableName OFFSET :Offset ROWS FETCH NEXT 10000 ROWS ONLY";
 cmd1.CommandText = selectStatement;
 var numParam = new OracleParameter();
 numParam.ParameterName = "Offset";
 numParam.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int32;
 numParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
 numParam.Value = offsetvalue;  

cmd1.Parameters.Add(numParam);
```

I have removed the semi-colon from the query and also used the parameter as :Offset , rather than @Offset
Thanks

Comment: Try removing the semicolon from the SQL statement.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I also made another change. I have updated the code in the main question. Hope it helps others as well.